# How to use Xamarin.Auth for UWP Login renderer

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth, xamarin.uwp

Xamarin.Auth 1.3.2 version was [support UWP app](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/1.3.2).
I have created and implemented app in Android and IOS like below

```html
PresentViewController (auth.GetUI (), true, null);
```

and for Android:

```html
StartActivity (auth.GetUI (this));
```

I want to get know how to use auth.GetUI() in xamarin.Form  UWP renderer .

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `auth.GetUI ()` in UWP project is  `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page`. So you can create custom `PageRenderer` in your UWP project and set native control as `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page` just like the following code.

**Usage**

```
public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
               SetNativeControl(new NativeLoginPage());    
            }
        }          
    }
```

**NativeLoginPage**

Add frame for the NativeLoginPage  `<Frame x:Name="Myframe " />`.

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
         clientId: "",
         scope: "",
         authorizeUrl: new Uri(""),
         redirectUrl: new Uri("")
         );
     auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
     var page = auth.GetUI();
     Myframe.Navigate(auth.GetUI());
 }

 private void Auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.IsAuthenticated)
     {
     }
     else
     {
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks , I have tried above code  but (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page).Frame is return null

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem and I have followed the post since the beginning because I am trying to do the same thing at the same time. I have a shared project and a iOS project and a UWP project (no Android on my behalf). I have no problem with iOS, it works like a charm. But, I cannot finalize the PageRenderer with UWP.

So I followed the recommandations of Nico Zhu. I added a Xaml User Control in my UWP project. I also added the frame in Xaml as mentionned above. But when the statement Myframe.Navigate(auth.GetUI()) is executed, I got a "Xaml parsing failed" error

But then I found this: http://damianblog.com/2016/09/04/uwp-oauth-in-xamarin-forms-using-xamarin-auth/. 
I followed the instructions mentionned in it and it worked perfectly.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this (mostly) working on UWP. Details in the thread at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/146 . Details of the (mostly) also in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to your question is the following code snippet for UWP:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame root_frame = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame;
root_frame.Navigate(auth.GetUI(), auth);
```